# Compare JSON List with JSON Dict; only by Keys

Tags: json, python-3.x, compare, key

I have a List and a dict which need to be compared just by the Keys.
The List is created by Hand for define which Vars will be used in the following process. The List will be used for writing the result in an CSV List = Header.

Some Devices doesn't support all Vars and won't send them Back in the response.

```
base=["General.IpAddress", "General.ActualHostname", "General.UserLabel1", "General.UserLabel2"]

response_diff='{"general.actualhostname":"ST_38_217","general.ipaddress":"192.168.38.217"}'
```

As you see the `General.UserLabel1` and `General.UserLabel2`is missing in the response. (There can be missing more vars)
So i have to add to the response the missing Vars with NULL Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json
from pprint import pprint


def compare_ListWithDict(list_base,dict_ref):
    #temp dict
    dict_base_tmp = {}
    dict_ref = dict_ref.lower()
    #run thru List an generate an dict with Value 0 for every Key
    for item in list_base:
        dict_base_tmp[item.lower()] = 0
    #load dict_ref as JSON
    dict_ref_json=json.loads(dict_ref)
    #get len
    dict_base_len= len(dict_base_tmp)
    dict_ref_len= len(dict_ref_json)
    #if lens are equal return the dict_ref (response from Device)
    if dict_base_len == dict_ref_len:   
        return dict_ref_json
    else:
        #run thru list_base and search for keys they AREN'T in dict_ref_json
        #if missing key is found, add the key with Value NULL to the dict_ref_json
        for item in list_base:
            if not item.lower() in dict_ref_json.keys():
                item_lower = item.lower()
                dict_ref_json[item_lower]='null'
        return dict_ref_json            

base=["General.IpAddress", "General.ActualHostname", "General.UserLabel1", "General.UserLabel2"]
response_diff='{"general.actualhostname":"ST_38_217","general.ipaddress":"192.168.38.217"}'
response_equal='{"general.actualhostname":"ST_38_217","general.ipaddress":"192.168.38.217","general.userlabel1":"First Label", "general.userlabel2":"Second Label"}'
```

Results:

```
  pprint(compare_ListWithDict(base,response_equal))
  #base and response are equal by the keys

    {'general.actualhostname': 'st_38_217',
     'general.ipaddress': '192.168.38.217',
     'general.userlabel1': 'first label',
     'general.userlabel2': 'second label'}

    pprint(compare_ListWithDict(base,response_diff))    
    #base and response is different by the keys

    {'general.actualhostname': 'st_38_217',
     'general.ipaddress': '192.168.38.217',
     'general.userlabel1': 'null',
     'general.userlabel2': 'null'}
```